# Access violation error on inserting data to map variable

Tags: c++

I have declared a map variable in header file and trying to insert some values to this from a method in cpp file.

In header (`.h`) file,

```
class Test
{
public:
    void AddName(const std::string& name, const std::string& value);
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m_names;
};
```

In `.cpp` file,

```
void Test::AddName(const std::string& name, const std::string& value)
{
    m_names.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(name, value));
}
```

> This method throws the error: "0xC0000005: Access violation reading
>   location 0x0000000000000150."

But if I declare this map variable with in this `AddName method`, then no error.

I am calling this AddName method from another class with required parameters.

```
TestPtr test = nullptr;
test->AddName(nodeDetails.Attribute("Name"), nodeDetails.Attribute("Value"));
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Do you have an actual `Test` object, or is it null? Also, not enough context for where `m_names` is declared (inside class?).

Comment: how is Addname called and how is Test object created?

Comment: @crashmstr I got why it is throwing this exception from your question. should not assign nullptr to test object.

Comment: @Joe You have no need for a pointer here. Also, you should never access any members or methods on a `nullptr` (undefined results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test` object has to be instancied before being used :

```
TestPtr test;
test.addName(...);
```

or dynamically allocated (using `new`)

```
TestPtr* test = new TestPtr();
test->AddName(...);
//
//...
//    
//And don't forget to free memory
delete test;
```

(in your case, the first method is more "memory safe" ;) )